# Code generations options/suggestions for .Net Core/.Net 6?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, csharp-source-generator

I've been working on a project where I want to read xml or json file and generate exception files off of it. I looked into different options which are mainly working for .Net framework but not .NetCore nor .Net6.

1- XSLT 1.0 (supported but no XSLT 2.0 nor 3.0 except you use third parties)

2- T4 template (Working only for .Net framework according to [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/support-loading-of-net-core-libraries-in-t4-templa/881587).

3- Source Generators, which tediously require developers to restart visual studio to generate code every time they change their generator code. According to [this](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/48083). This means that you can't see the newly generated code until you restart visual studio. Any solution/workaround to this issue? I can't get this to work as I expected, I need to generate code and build it as part of my solution build.

The requirement I need to meet is to support .Net Core 3.1 or .Net 6 as well but we can't go with older versions. Also, I need to have control over specifying the access modifier for the fields in the generated code. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you're confused about that SG issue. You need to restart VS when *developing* the source generator, if you're developing it by debugging it directly in VS, rather than doing the recommended thing of using unit tests. The development experience when using unit tests is just fine. Once your SG is written, it will re-generate its output on every build just fine, no need to restart anything.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still developing the source generator, and using unit tests in that early phase is going to make it hard IMO rather than easily see what happens when you do something. Also, I didn't get your point when you said " Once your SG is written, it will re-generate its output on every build just fine ", is this happening for you? I've tried .Net 6/.Net 5 with VS 19/22 and still I get same behavior where I need to restart VS to get the new generated code.

Comment: I've written two fairly large SGs. I've tried multiple ways of developing, and trust me, using unit tests from the get-go is the easiest way to go about things. You can debug into the unit tests which gives you exacty the same debugging experience, but you don't need to launch multiple instances of VS or deal with the restarting issue. Heck your unit tests don't even need to have any assertions: just treat them as a way to debug into the SG with a known set of inputs if you want. Yes, once written my SGs have always run on every build (normally on every keystroke), and re-generate their output

Comment: Just because a T4 template that uses .NET Framework to read JSON or XML files **in no way implies that the generated code also depends on .NET Framework.** The shape of the output is entirely up to you.  To demonstrate you could make it spit out INI files; c/c++ or objective-c if you really wanted to.  T4 is the quickest means to an end and can be executed automatically.  T4 supports both coding-time and run-time generation

Comment: …also you can plonk a T4 template **.TT** file into a .NET Core project where it will quite happily run at coding time.  That’s because they have nothing to do with your .NET Core project at _execution time_

Comment: @canton7 let me look into this a little more, I actually used the sample that Microsoft has in their documentation but it never re-generates unless I restart my VS as I mentioned. If you figured out a way, maybe you can update the open issue I shared in my question related to that. [Here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/48083)

Comment: @canton7 Can you please share a sample of your code?

Comment: Sure, knock yourself out: https://github.com/canton7/PropertyChanged.SourceGenerator

Comment: @MickyD Thanks dude, I actually tried again yesterday and could get it to work with 2 project, .Netstandard for the models and .NetCore 3.1 but when I tried with .Net6, it didn't, it complains about the System.Runtime version 6.0.0. I will look into that more later when we move our project to .Net 6.

Comment: You’re welcome.  Hope it works out :)